# Preferences aren't saving between runs

Tags: java, android

So I am using preferences to store small amounts of data instead of a database. I have two relevant functions, where lines represents the data.

```
private ArrayList<String> readFile() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        lines = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = prefs.getInt("lines_size",0);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            lines.add(prefs.getString(("Line_"+i), null));
        }

        return lines;
    }
```

and

```
private SharedPreferences.Editor update_prefs() {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1 = sp.edit();
        mEdit1.putInt("lines_size", lines.size());

        for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++)
        {
            mEdit1.remove("Line_" + i);
            mEdit1.putString("Line_" + i, lines.get(i));
            System.out.println("Line_" + i);
        }
        mEdit1.apply();
        mEdit1.commit();
        return mEdit1;
    }
```

Why doesn't this save the data?

Comment: `lines = new ArrayList<>(); return lines;` is that on purpose?

Comment: also, do you ever actually put something else in that array?

Comment: @njzk2 that was a layover from an earlier version, sorry will remove it